# Refering to environment variable in oracle sql files on Linux and Windows

Tags: oracle

We have an sql build script, with oracle 10.2. At the end of the script we have this:

```
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

Which works on Linux but not on Windows. So we created a second file with this line:

```
@%ORACLE_HOME%/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

Surely there is a better way. How can I refer to an environment variable in a cross-platform way? Or alternatively, is it possible to do OS detection in the sql file to guard each of the statements with an IF clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this syntax is what you need:

@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql

However, this is just for the ORACLE_HOME variable. I don't know about others...

Edit:

It's a bit awkward, but you could look into setting SQLPATH environment variable as well. It's to SQL scripts in oracle as PATH is to executables in Unix/Windows.

Comment: thanks, the question mark worked. Do you know perhaps where can I find documentation about it?

Comment: Here's a passing reference to it in the 8i Administrator's Reference (for SGI Irix, how's that for a blast from the past): http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A87435_01/ch3_sol.htm. It seems to be a SQL*Plus thing, but I haven't found it in that manual.